# Validations not being applied when using update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an object model which is quite nested. I can't give the real model but suffice to say it looks something like this:

- A has_many B
- B has_many C
- C has_many D

On each parent I have accepts_nested_attributes_for and the relevant attr_accessible entries and changing the state appears to be working ok. The problem I'm having is with validations.

Each object has it's own validations as to be expected. Furthermore for each parent I have added validates_associations to force the children to be validated on update. However if for example I have updated some fields in the children when I update A with update_attributes it's returning true when it should return false.

What's more peculiar is if I breakpoint, force the call to update_attributes in my IDE once and then let the code progress the second call to update_attributes seems to behave as expected.

Am I missing something really obvious?

**Apologies in advance for the really cr*p analogy for my object model**

Comment: Some debugging tips - put a few puts obj.valid? at different places and see if it is valid in the log. You can also try update_attributes!, which throws error in case of failure. We cannot help much without the actual code.

Comment: I seem to have discovered my problem. I put a debug statement in for before_validation on my lower most object and it showed the validation was getting called many times when it should have been only called once. I removed the validates_associated clauses from all the parents and it appears to have fixed it.